# ios uiimageview tap gesture not working during animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView` that is animated and receiving a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. The problem is while animated, the tap gesture area doesn't move with the view. I can tap the view's original location and the tap gesture is recognized. Anyone know how to have the tap recognized while the view is moving and not at its original position?

Edit 1:
This is how I've set up my tap gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
    tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapRecognizer.delegate = (id)self;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Is there a way to have the gesture recognizer follow my view on its path since my animation lasts a couple seconds? Have I missed a setting?

Edit 2:
This is my code to set up my animation:

```
    double width = backgroundImageView.frame.size.width;
    double height = backgroundImageView.frame.size.height;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    double startX = -imageView.frame.size.width;
    double startY = height/4;
    double endX = 3*width;
    double endY = 0;
    double duration = 40;
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, startX, startY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, endX, endY);
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.duration = duration;
    animation.path = path;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"theAnimation"];
```

Comment: can you show the code of animation ?

Comment: I added the code I have for setting up my animation.

Comment: I tried a test by animating a UIButton on a path and it does the same thing. If I make the animation last 30 seconds, the whole time its moving, I can tap on its original spot and it will be "as if" the button is not animated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved my problem. Simply use an `NSTimer`, check and update the `UIImageView`'s `frame` from the presentation `layer` by:

```
CGRect viewLocation = [[[imageView layer] presentationLayer] frame];    
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(viewLocation.origin.x, viewLocation.origin.y, viewLocation.size.width, viewLocation.size.height);
```

After that, touches work wherever my image view is :-)