# tap event does not fire on animated imageview

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want an animating imageView with `UIBezierPath` (sliding from top to bottom) to be clicked. But every google help I found didn't solve it. But it does not print "clicked".

The animation does work perfectly. Maybe anyone's got a clue?

Help is very appreciated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "advent_button"))
    let dimension = 25 + drand48() * 30
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dimension, height: dimension)

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleImageTap))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.path = customPath().cgPath
    animation.duration = 20
    animation.fillMode = .forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.repeatCount = 0.5
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)

    imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    view.addSubview(imageView)        
}

@objc func handleImageTap() {
    print ("clicked")
}

func customPath() -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 0))
    let endpoint = CGPoint(x: 20 , y: 700)
    let cp1 = CGPoint(x: 90, y: 250)
    let cp2 = CGPoint(x: 180, y: 400)
    path.addCurve(to: endpoint, controlPoint1: cp1, controlPoint2: cp2)
    return path
}
```

Comment: why you are not using uibutton instead of uiimageview. then no need to add gesture

Comment: Did you try this? Use NSTimer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287267/ios-uiimageview-tap-gesture-not-working-during-animation

Comment: The same behavior by using a button.

Answer (score 0):

I got your issue. i am sure you are touching layer not `UIImageView` and you have added `uitapgesturerecognizer` to `UIImageview` not layer. Do one thing set

animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true

and set  `imageView.frame` similar co- ordinates where animation will stop

Full code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Icon123"))
        imageView.backgroundColor = .red
      //  let dimension = 25 + drand48() * 30

        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: 50, height: 50)

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleImageTap))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.path = customPath().cgPath
        animation.duration = 5
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        animation.repeatCount = 0.5
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)

        imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        view.addSubview(imageView)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    @objc func handleImageTap() {
        print ("clicked")
    }

    func customPath() -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 0))
        let endpoint = CGPoint(x: 20 , y: 700)
        let cp1 = CGPoint(x: 90, y: 250)
        let cp2 = CGPoint(x: 180, y: 400)
        path.addCurve(to: endpoint, controlPoint1: cp1, controlPoint2: cp2)
        return path
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean by using similar coordinates?

Comment: I mean to say, if you want to set your imageview at position, where animation of layer end. then you have to set frame at that location by using imageview.frame property or imageview.center

Comment: And do not forget to use animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true

Comment: if I set .isRemovedOnCompletion = true the animation will not even start

Comment: let me paste my code, i have edit. should i upload gif as well. its perfect on my end. you have to set frame of imageview after completion of animation

Comment: Thank you for your post. But the animation is completed and so the image can be tapped. I put the code in viewDidAppear and I can't tap the image WHILE animation :(

Comment: Bro, you are animating(moving) layer. but you have added gesture on view. that's why its going on. you have to change frame of imageview within this  UIView.animate(withDuration: <#T##TimeInterval#>, animations: <#T##() -> Void#>)  to have tap gesture on animation

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 30, delay: delay, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.button.frame = CGRect(
            x: randomXEndShift,
            y: 700,
            width: dimension,
            height: dimension)
    }, completion: nil)
```

Shows the same behavoir. Even using  `.allowUserInteraction` does not help at all.